# Limits for external facing Community page?

Tags: community

I know we can make some page public access in Community. But what are limits for this? I do Not mean internal limits like SOQL, but limits for traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you'll be using Sites for any external facing pages? If yes, limits can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_public_access_settings.htm), including bandwidth cap, pageviews, and service request time